# How update fields in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I want to update few fields in my table. How it is update query write in lumen. I want to update salutation, name, lastname, address fields with dynamicaly equal to id.
 `$query = "UPDATE`passengers`SET`name`= ? WHERE (`id`='1') ";
        $update = app('db')->update($query, [$passenger->name,]);`

I want to pass id value as dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `update()` method with `where()`:

```
DB::table('passengers')->where('id', $id)->update(['name' => $name, 'lasname' => $lastname]);
```

Comment: Class 'Passenger\\Data\\Eloquent\\Repositories\\MySQL\\DB' not found

Comment: @user2552863 just use full namespace `\DB` or add `use DB;` to the top of the class.

Comment: in lumen I got the answer with  app('db')->table

Comment: @user2552863 yes, in Lumen you can do `app('db')->table('passengers')->where('id', $id)->update(['name' => $name, 'lasname' => $lastname]);`

Comment: @user2552863 please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Use update

```
DB::table('passengers')->where('id', $id)->update(['name' => $name, 'lasname' => $lastname]);

 $update = app('db')->table('passengers')->where('id', $id)->update(['name' => $name, 'lasname' => $lastname]);
```

Comment: You've just copied the code from my answer and then from my comment. You even copied the error I have (lasname).